# I want to pass in an Expression into another expression in a flask jinja2 for Loop to Load an image page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to pass in an Expression into another expression in a flask jinja2 for Loop to Load an image page

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% include 'includes/items_modals.html' %}

        <div class="card-deck"  style="width:250px; height:350px">
        <div class="card bg-dark" style="width: 18rem; margin-top:20px">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/{{item.img_path}}')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title" >{{item.name}}</h4>
                <p class="card-text" style="color:green; font-weight:bold">₦{{item.price}}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Depending on what an `item` is, hat snippet looks o.k. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: all the items are displaying except for the image because it's a nested jinja2